# How can I create a simple hook in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, githooks, bitbucket-pipelines

It is possible to create a server-side hook in Bitbucket for reject push if the pipeline fails?

I am reading about these possibilities but only in Bitbucket Server and not on the bitbucket website.

Any idea or tutorial about how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking about a pre-receive hook, which is not currently supported in Bitbucket Cloud.

On the larger question, though: if the pipeline fails, then shouldn't somebody be able to push the fix?

Comment: Yes, but we are work with PR, and we want to avoid failed states in history

Comment: Why do you want to avoid failed states in history? How will that work when the test fails - do you destroy the branch and start fresh?

Comment: The idea is the same like pre-commit, but for ensure that anyone user  forget set they pre-commit hooks we want ensure the serve with a pre-recibe hook